# QuartzCore Border Doesn't Look Flat

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, quartz-core

When I use:

```
yourTextField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
yourTextField.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
```

the border doesn't look like all sides are 1.0 pixel wide. Is there come kind of shadow or something that doesn't make it look flat?

Anyone know how to correct this

Comment: Is its textField's frame integral?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the text field?